# Action sheet not displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am trying to display an action sheet with a progress bar imbedded in it during downloads. The sheet doesn't display during downloads and when the download is done, the screen dims as if it is going to present the sheet and the UI is dead. I assume there is some blocking activity going on and it needs to be on another thread or something but I am not familiar with the iOS threading model yet. I also assume because I've removed the sheet, that is why the display is dim. How can I dismiss it? The code to set the sheet up is:

```
self.pActionSheet=[[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Downloading Alerts. Please Wait.\n\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        pBarView=[[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,40.0f, 220.0f, 90.0f)];
        [pBarView setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
        [pActionSheet addSubview:pBarView];
        [pBarView release];
        [pBarView setProgress:0.0f];
        [pActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        pBarView.center=CGPointMake(pActionSheet.center.x,pActionSheet.center.y);
        pAmt=1.0/(float)totalDownload;
```

The statement to dismiss it is: `[pActionSheet removeFromSuperView[;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the download on another thread with `performSelectorInBackground:` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Use the dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:  - method to dismiss the action sheet ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: Thanks. The dismiss work but both your references point to the actionsheet doc. Do you have the other reference handy? No big deal if not, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the link now.

Comment: Everything but the progress bar is working. It does not show up in the action sheet. The sheet pops up and says, downloading data, etc. but no bar. Is there something I'm missing in the setup?

Comment: I don't think that a UIActionSheet is appropriate for displaying an UIProgressBar. I'd suggest that you create a view with the progress bar and add it using presentModalViewController.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this will helps you

```
UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select Sharing Option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"E-Mail",nil];
popup.tag = 1;
[popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```